# How to I determine the value of a bar in a bar chart (Highchart) on user click?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have a Highchart that renders according to data in my database. I also currently have a table that renders with the correct values when I pass in a value such as "A" or "C" manually, but I'd like the table to render according to an onClick event, when a user clicks on a bar in my Highchart.

For each corresponding value below, such as @a_sum, I have an array called @a with string values in it that will be passed into the chart.

I've Googled around without much luck. I'm wondering how I get the value of the bar in the char when a user clicks on that specific bar.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var chart1; // globally available
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title : {
            text: "Most Effective Referral Sources"
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',  'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
        },
        yAxis: {   
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 60,
            x: -60
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
        },
        series: [{
            data: [<%= @a_sum %>, <%= @b_sum %>, <%= @c_sum %>, <%= @d_sum %>,  <%= @e_sum %>, <%= @f_sum %>, <%= @g_sum %>, <%= @h_sum %>, <%= @i_sum %>, <%= @j_sum %>,  <%= @k_sum %>, <%= @l_sum %>]
        }]
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: "but I'd like the table to render according to an onClick event, when a user clicks on a bar in my Highchart." - can you elaborate a little bit on the question here? I'm not sure if I understand. Do you mean you want to render another table based on onclick event of the bar?

Comment: Sure thing, @fatshu I have the table all ready to go, it fills in its values based on the instance variable selected in the chart. Currently, it doesn't change its values unless I change the code by hand, I'd like what's in the table to change according to the bar that the user clicks on in the chart. Does that make more sense?

Comment: did the solution below work for you? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want (if I understand you question correctly) is to implement the event in the plotOptions above:
    http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-column-point-events--click

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
         point: {
             events: {
         click: function() {
                     // use this to trigger showing/hiding the specific table you need
                     console.log(this)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

For example, this is a sample of the console log I got:

```
Lc
_high: 417
...
series: c
...
x: 20
y: 33
__proto__: Object
```

With this.series you should be able to get the parameters on the series whose column you click, and then call your "enableTableForDataSeries" function to enable the specific data series.